# how do I change url from $stateChangeStart whithout changing the state and prevent calling $stateChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to change the url without triggering  `$stateChangeSuccess` and wiout changing the state . When an element is exists it should change the url and scroll to the element. I am able to scroll but not able to change the url. Sorry for my poor English.

Here is my code.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl, fromState, fromParams) { //No I18N

    var l = ($location.$$path).split("/");
    l.shift();
    var step = l[1];

    if (step != "step4") return

    var module = l[2];

    if (newUrl.data.elementExists(module)) {

        var el = document.getElementById("SECTION" + module.hashCode());
        ZCScrollComponents.scrollTo(ZCDocumentationContainer, el.offsetTop, 300, null);

        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go(fromState.name, null, {
            notify: false,
            location: true
        });
    }
})
```